# Passing result of a query as parameter in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am new to crystal report, I have a report to generate which contains two queries.
I need to run the first query which returns a single column.
I need to fetch the result of the first query one by one and pass it as a parameter to the second query. And finally running the second query.

> It would be helpful if anyone tell me the steps about how to do this.
>   I am using crystal report 2008, I hope the above mentioned information is sufficient, if not please let me know.

Comment: I just know how to run a query and pass the user parameters to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use sub reports for this purpose...

Take query 1 in main repoirt and query 2 in sub report. Place the sub report in the section that is coming after the data in main report.

Then pass the filed of mail report to sub report using the sub report links and then apply condition on this field in sub report `Record Selection Formula`

Comment: This is working fine. What to do if I want to show the result of the first query as the dropdown options and want to select them as a parameter for the second query.

Comment: Create a paramter in sub report and when linking to sub report link this value to that parameter and check

Comment: could you please explain the above step in detail.

Comment: I mean to say you are passing some values to sub report...correct? so when you link link that field to parameter in sub report...and check are you aable to get what I am trying to say?